# Yii2 rest api not found

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-rest

In advanced-app i create new module api (just copy backend).

[image]

And fix route in OpenServer:

[image]

Set RestApi Settings like this: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start

But for url http://api/users I get 404

How fix it?

Git link: https://github.com/triest/Insigne/tree/master/api

Comment: You messed up something with namespaces. Why you're using `backend` namespace for API?

Comment: try accessing api/robots.txt. You should see the content, if it does not work then something is set up in the wrong way on your server. Also is the 404 error an Yii2 error or a normal server error. This could actually tell us a lot.

Answer (score -1):

In config/main.php need fix 'controllerNamespace'